# Do I need to include Key attributes of all Global Secondary Indices when doing UpdateItem in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a table with these columns:

- subscription_id
- email
- order_id
- updated_at
- note

and two secondary indices attached to it. 1 index is using Key field `email` and another - `order_id`.

When I do `UpdateItem` for the table, where I change only `note`, `updated_at` (and using key `subscription_id`), I get an error returned `The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value."`. However, I do not use any attribute which is a Key for a GSI.

Does that mean that after I have any GSI attached to the table, I need to always include all of their Key attributes in the `UpdateItem` calls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the problem was that item, which I was updating, had a property, which was a GSI Key, set to an empty string. I understood the root cause from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58060628/309852).

To fix the problem I had to update my database to remove all non-conformant fields.

Answer (score -1):

No, it simply means it cannot be null. GSI keys must be one of String, Number or Binary.

You are getting the exception because while you are only updating certain values you are implicitly setting the others to null or empty strings, which leads me to believe you are using some sort of data mapper such as the Mapper Client for Java.

Ensure that you exclude the attributes which you are not updating, i.e do not set them to Null or empty values.

Comment: I do not understand this part of your answer: how do I "exclude the attributes I'm not updading", if I "implicitly set them to null"?

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: AWS SDK for Golang